# Git error when installing with Vundle

Tags: git, vim, macvim

I recently installed and have been using MacVim on OS X 10.11.5, and I wanted to install some plugins. I installed Vundle successfully, however I'm encountering errors when I try to install plugins using Vundle. The plugin I'm trying to install is [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). What I did is type `:PluginInstall YouCompleteMe`, however, when I execute this, I get the following error:

```
"fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured"
```

This is strange; I have a GitHub account, but I'm not being promoted for it. I'm very new to git, so any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the [error log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFx4.png)

Update:

I ran the clone from the command prompt, and it worked, but I would like to be able to manage it from inside MacVim. Additionally, the URL MacVim was using was wrong. I had to go to the page itself and get a different URL. I would like to automate this inside MacVim if possible. Even using SSH instead of HTTPS doesn't fix the incorrect URL issue.

Comment: Using the ssh url instead of the https url will probably fix it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How would I configure MacVim to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ssh instead of https:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Then try again the plugin installation: any https://github.com access should now use an ssh url.

Similarly:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/vim-scripts/YouCompleteMe.git".insteadOf "https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git"
```

That will "automate this inside MacVim".

If you have a local repo with the wrong url:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
```

Comment: I tried this, however MacVim seems to have the incorrect URL. The repository at the URL MacVim has is non-existent, and I don't know how to change it to the proper one. The one MacVim has: https://github.com/vim-scripts/YouCompleteMe.git The right one: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git

Comment: mvim is an editor, not a repo. If you have a local repo, `git remote set-url origin xxx` is the way to change its remote url.